# Question about a step in a derangement proof

Tags: discrete-mathematics, recurrence-relations, derangements

I read a proof about derangement and I didn't understand this step:

$d_n - nd_{n-1} = -(d_{n-1}-(n-1)d_{n-2}) \implies d_n=nd_{n-1}+(-1)^n$

---

I see that we have $S_n = -S_{n-1}$ if $S$ is the stuff on one side of the equation but I don't get what happened then. Where does $(-1)^n$ come from?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second equation doesn't follow from just the first equation you wrote here. That equation has to be understood as a recurrence, and then it implies
$S_n = (-1)^n K$ for some constant $K$ and $n$ in the range where the recurrence works.

Now you need an appropriate $K,$ which might be $S_m$ or $-S_m$ for integer $m.$

If $K = 1$ then you have $S_n = (-1)^n,$ which implies the second equation.

Comment: I plugged in $d_4 = 9$ and $d_5 = 44$ and got $9 - 4*2 = -(2-(4-1)1)$ and $44-5*9=-(9-(5-1)2)$. The first equation leads to $-1=-1$ and the second one to $1=1$. The $(-1)^n$ makes a little bit more sense to me now. But why is this true for all $n$? I know that $d_n = (n-1)(d_{n-1}+d_n-2))$ and that $d_n - nd_{n-1} = -(d_{n-1}-(n-1)d_{n-2})$ follows from that. But I still don't understand $d_n=nd_{n-1}+(-1)^n$ to be honest.

Comment: It should be $d_n = (n-1)(d_{n-1}+d_{n-2})$ of course. I already proved that btw.

Comment: You start at some $S_m$, suppose it's $S_2$, then $S_3=-S_2$, $S_4=S_2,$ $S_5=-S_2,$ $S_6=S_2,$ and so forth. The sign keeps alternating, just like $(-1)^n$, so the pattern is $S_n=(-1)^n S_2.$ And it's only true for $n$ for which the underlying formulas for $S_n$ make sense. I don't know how to evaluate $d_{-1}$ so I wouldn't write $S_0.$ Now if you  know that $S_2=1,$ perhaps by simply trying each permutation, you know $S_n=(-1)^n$ for $n\geq2.$ Now actually write that equation out in terms of $d_n$ and $d_{n-1}$ and see if it doesn't imply the last equation.

Answer (score 0):

You could show this recurrence using the formula for the derangement numbers (proven using the principle of inclusion-exclusion): $$d_n = n!\sum^n_{i=0}\frac{(-1)^i}{i!}$$